# How to properly set up Docker container for local curling?

Tags: docker

I get

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

when I try to curl a simple docker container at `localhost:8080` with an app listening on `localhost:8080` of the container.

I've started my docker container with:

```
 docker run -p 8080:8080 -it <image-name>
```

And within the app's config contained inside `<image-name>`, I've tried telling it to run on the following hosts:

```
host: localhost # (or 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 0.0.0.0)
port: 8080
```

Only `0.0.0.0` has worked, but I don't want to use that.

I would like to have a host that isn't `0.0.0.0` in my app config that will let me curl the healthcheck endpoint of my app via:

```
curl localhost:8080/health
```

on my local machine. What am I missing?

Comment: Actually it has to be 0.0.0.0 and it should actually be 0.0.0.0 because it means that your app will be accessible to all the clients including your local client that is trying to connect to the server inside docker.

Comment: As you might already know, docker exposes the docker port to local port so that you can do localhost:8080/health and the request is served by the docker container. But from a request perspective, it start in your local machine, where it gets proxied to (probably) the docker container, and that request is not local to that container anymore. That is the reason for 0.0.0.0 so that server inside the docker container is open to serve all requests, including the ones coming from your host machine.

Comment: Quick answer is - docker set-up own network, smth about 172.x.x.x. Run docker inspect command to find it. Then you will its IP, but it is the only intermediate solution.

Comment: @Rash and @h__, so there's no way to map to a specific host within the container, similar to the `-p 8080:8080` port mapping? I can't say, "map the request from my `localhost` to the docker container's `localhost`"? What host is it getting mapped to in the container with a simple `curl localhost:8080/health` and my existing `docker run ...` command?

Comment: When you start a server, like nginx or apache, they take a host parameter which tells them the name of their host. If you set it to localhost, then it means name of host is 127.0.0.1 which is local to the docker machine at this point. If you set it to your host machine IP i.e. 192.x.x.x then it will be able to serve requests from any machine connected to your home router. Why? because when you request, you say where to send the request to - so only those machine which can access the host can send the requests. When you say localhost, your host machine cannot reach localhost of docker machine.

Comment: ok, I think I know where your confusion is coming from. Any machine may have multiple network interfaces. Docker containers always have 2 or more. One localhost, other is the 172.x.x.x address that is the docker network address. Docker uses the 172 address for port forwarding. So in your host when you say localhost:8080 the request goes to your host first, then gets proxied to docker's 172 address, but your server is not listening on the 172 address, it is listening on 127.0.0.1 Since you don't always know what is the IP of host, you set it to 0.0.0.0 which means all interfaces.

Comment: @Rash, thank you so much! That really helps clear things up. So, the request gets mapped from localhost to Docker's network IP. Then, the request is forwarded to the IP of the Docker network with the specified port (8080 in this example) inside the Docker network. If the app (living inside the Docker network) is only listening on localhost, that doesn't match the Docker network IP. But if the app is listening on 0.0.0.0, it will find it, as long as it's running on port 8080. Seems the only way to get the Docker network's localhost exposed would be with some Docker network magic. Is that right?

Comment: Correct except the last part. There is no specific docker magic. Imagine you have a setup where you have a nginx server as a load balancer with your actual server running somewhere. The nginx will forward request to your server. This is the same setup as your host forwarding request to docker server. In this new example if you would have set localhost as your host, you cannot send request to it like this - `http://10.0.0.34/health` even if you can reach `10.0.0.34` because the server is not listening there. Same way, think docker of another machine.